# Auto-width a child div with a parent with fixed width and overflow: hidden

Tags: css, width, overflow, css-float

My problem is a bit difficult to explain. I would like a div to stretch so all of his floated childs stays on the same line. The problem is that the parent of the container has a fixed width and his overflow is hidden.

The idea is that div.container stretch (should be 1100px in my example) so the div.thumb stays on the same line.

Here is the example on JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TdHYg/3/

```
<div class ="viewport">
<div class="container">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

```
.viewport {
border:1px black solid;
overflow:hidden;
width:400px;   
}

.container {
/* width:1100px*/
}

.thumb{
background-color:lightgray;
margin:5px;
width:100px;   
height:100px;    
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does http://jsfiddle.net/f2WeB/ fully meet your requirements? Let's hope so! display: inline-block is supported from Safari 2 on, from Opera 9 on, from IE8 on and from Firefox 3 on.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot. Anyway, I stop support for IE7- since Google did.

Answer (score 1):

Add another container around the `thumbs`:

http://jsfiddle.net/TdHYg/4/

Comment: The thing is I don't want to specify div.container width, because the div.thumbs childs dynamically changes with Javascript... I could, of course, calculate the width of the container with JS, but I would prefer a 100% CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can save Xander's div by surrounding the containing floats with a float: http://jsfiddle.net/TdHYg/5/. This brings you to "float nearly everything". But there are other methods like clearing: http://jsfiddle.net/TdHYg/7/.

Or may you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/TdHYg/6/?

Comment: The thing is I don't want to specify div.container width, because the div.thumbs childs dynamically changes with Javascript... I could, of course, calculate the width of the container with JS, but I would prefer a 100% CSS solution.